# SAPUI5 List Item context binding, get the next path

Tags: sapui5

I have a table of list items (questions) and I want to be able to re-arrange them. See screenshot.

[image: Binding Context]

Currently, on the button down press, I can get the current binding context and I am getting that sequence property (001). What I want to be able to do is also be able to get the path of the next list items binding context (002 in this case).

Current code...

```
// Move Question Down
onQuestionMoveDown: function (oEvent) {
    // Get binding context
    var source = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("view");
    var path = source.getPath();
    var object = source.getModel().getProperty(path);
    var currentQuestionSequence = object.Sequence;

    MessageToast.show("Current # " + currentQuestionSequence);
}
```

Then once I have that I can sort my updates logic.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be that you have an order value on your model and you update that order when the user clicks on the button.
If the list is sorted by that value you will achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The items should be bound to the table via list binding, and so the data set would be an Array, the path for each line will be like ".../itemSet/0, .../itemSet/1, ...". So possible solution could be:

```html
function getNextItem(oItem){
  var oContext = oItem.getBindingContext("view"), // assumpe the model name is view
     sPath  = oContext.getPath(),
     sSetPath  = sPath.substr(0, sPath.lastIndexOf("/")),
     iMaxLen  = oContext.getProperty(sSetPath).length,
     iCurIndex = parseInt(sPath.substr(sPath.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
  
  // If it's already reach to be bottom, return undefined
  return iCurIndex < iMaxLen -1 ? oContext.getProperty(sSetPath + "/" + ++iCurIndex) : undefined;
}
```

Regards,
Marvin